# Facebook Graph API rate limiting Headers issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook clearly mentions it returns Rate limiting headers ( [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting#what-do-we-consider-an-api-call-) )

But I can't see the headers in the response

Endpoint : `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{post_id}/reactions?summary=true&limit=0`

Headers :

[image: Response headers]

The request is made using an app `access_token` if I use a page access token I can see the headers, but using an app access token I can't.

Am I missing something?

Comment: _“if I use a page access token I can see the headers, but using an app access token I can't.”_ - well then you simply reached (or at least are close to) the limit with the page token, but not with your app token. That those are _different_, and that the headers will only be set if your app is currently limited or close, is also mentioned clearly in the docs ...

Comment: Thanks buddy, i don't know how i missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some experience with Facebook's Graph API. Individual applications only start to be rate limited by Facebook once they start getting close to the rate restrictions on a regular basis. You won't see the headers until then. And not all endpoints are subject to rate limiting. It's a kind web service!